# Store millisecond value using hibernate @CreationTimestamp annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using the following code in my entity

```
@CreationTimestamp
private LocalDateTime responseDateTime;
```

This is working fine, however is storing the date in format `2021-02-15 21:26:39`. How can I get this date to store with a millisecond value?

Thanks

Comment: It would be useful to provide the definition of column in database - what type of the column that this dateTime is persisted to? Because it can be issue with the column itself not being able to store such data

Comment: The column is of type DATETIME. This is automatically generated by hibernate

Comment: Please also share information about used DB - as there can be minor differences.

Comment: I am using MySQL v8.0.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that issue is mostly related to the actual type of column in your database.
Looks like it would be better to use DATETIME(3) type - as it allows to have fractional second information.
More information can be found at [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html)

Comment: Brilliant tyvm. For those wondering how can you tell hibernate this.. use '@Column(columnDefinition = "DATETIME(3)")' - 3 being the fractional second precision you wish.